# Input Background Image in grid using html and css

Tags: html, css, image, background, grid

I am trying to put Background Image in one of my column grid but it won't show i tried to stretch it but it doesn't look good. i don't know what is missing or is there a code that are not suppost to be there. i looked in every forum but there's no specific answer or question that is related to my problem.

```css
    body {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 100%;
      grid-template-rows: 10vw 50vw 50vw 50vw 50vw 7vw;
      grid-gap: .5em;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;

      
    }

    header,
    footer {
      grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    }

    main {
      grid-column: 1 / span 2;
      grid-column: 1 / span 2;
      grid-column: 1 / span 2;
      grid-column: 1 / span 2;
      
    }

    #main1 {
     background: url("Pics&Video/Sea.jpg") no-repeat center;
     background-size: contain;
     
     
    }


    body {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 80em;
      padding: 1em 0;
    }

    header,
    main,
    aside,
    footer {
      background: #eaeaea;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
```

```html
<header>
      Header
     </header>
     
     <main class="main1"> 
      Main
     </main >
     <main class="main2">
      main
     </main>
     <main class="main3">
      Main
     </main>
     <main class="main4">
      main
     </main>

     <footer>
      Footer
     </footer>
```

[Sea.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7Rk2.jpg)

Comment: a class gets targeted by a `.` not an `#` so use it like `.main1` not `#main1`

Answer (score 0):

On HTML you are using class="main2" αnd on CSS you are using #. You should change on css .main1{}